# preg_replace to remove phone numbers from a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have website where i need to stop users from sending contact numbers/emails  to other users via mail ,

i am using this below in somewhat successfully, but it doenst do what i want to do i.e .. in matching all scenarios

```
public function clean_email($text){
    $pattern = '/\w+[\w-\.]*(\@\w+((-\w+)|(\w*))\.[a-z]{2,3})/i';
    preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);
    return (isset($matches[1])) ? str_replace($matches[1], 
            "[********]", $text) : $text;
}

public function clean_phone($text){
    $pattern = '/(\d{3}|\d{4})|(\d{3,+})/i';
    preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);
    return (isset($matches[1])) ? str_replace($matches[1], 
               "[********]", $text) : $text;
}
```

i am thinking of using preg_replace to identify a phone number in the mail text, however i am aware that phone numbers can be written in many way like below,

```
0433 765 888
0433765888
+61433765888
+610433765888
+61 02 9876 0987
+61 0298760987
+610298760987
```

is it possible to write a one single preg_replace pattern to identify them all ?

also need to do the same for the email address also i want to replace them with a [censored] in every email address we find in the email text.
i,e

```
mlanXXX@hotmail.com
mlanXXX AT hotmail.com
```

Any luck  ..

Comment: there will always be ways around this.

Comment: Whatever you try to block it, users will come with new tricks, replacing zero with "O letter", 1 with "small L", etc. There are thousands of possible scenarios. I'm pretty sure it's not possible to make it work for all of them.

Comment: `Call me at 47 double-O 617. Use country code 381 w/ plus prefix.`

Comment: call @Wh1T3h4Ck5 for a good time :-)

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of a widely used unit conversion extension for Firefox, so I have a lot of experience with how people write things in human language when they want to convey information in a non-adversarial setting. That is, when they are not hindered by an adversary who actively attempts to censor them. And I'm telling you, even in that context, it's impossible for regular expressions to **always** figure out what they're trying to convey.

I needed the long introduction in order to offer this answer: no, it can't be done. What you can do is engage in an arms race. That is, implement whatever minimalistic regexp works now, then continually monitor your users' communications and improve your regexp based on whatever they come up with in order to circumvent you.

Be advised however that you'll never find a satisfactory solution, because pretty soon you'll end up bogged down in annoying false positives. Take for instance "I found these shoes at amazon.com". Your code will change that to "I found these [censored]". Phone numbers are even worse, because people can write selected figures as words ("043three376five..."), so you'd end up having to censor all mentions of any numbers.

This is essentially a social problem that can't be fixed by technical means. What I would do if I were you is I'd implement the few obvious regexps (thus catching 99% of the candid users), and enforce the rule with social rules. That is, enforcing the EULA by kicking out people who try to circumvent it.